# How to add new elementor post programmatically?

Tags: wordpress, database-migration, elementor

I'm trying to migrate data from old site to the new site .. my new site is built using wordpress with elementor plugin to create templates and handling theme.

I need to insert posts programmatically and the post contains ***widget that is used inside elementor template file***

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress - Programmatically insert Elementor Widgets in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63898766/wordpress-programmatically-insert-elementor-widgets-in-a-page)